# Finding $p$ such that $k<px+qn<k+1$

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $0<x<1$. Let $k$ is any integer, and $n$ any positive integer. Fix $k,n$. If $q$ is such integer that $qn\le k<(q+1)n$, then how to show that there exists  positive integer $p$ such that $k<px+qn<k+1$?

Context: I am reading solution to Rudin exercise 25, ch 4. There it is mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that we must have $n>0$ because of $q_n \leq k < (q+1)n$.

Case 1: If $qn=k$, we can take $p=1$, because $$k<x+k=x+qn < k+1.$$

Case 2: Now, let $k >qn$, then take $p = \lceil (k - qn)/(x-\delta) \rceil$. Here, we have
$$k<\frac{(k-qn)}{x-\delta}x+qn \leq px+qn < \frac{(k-qn)}{x-\delta}x +x+qn < \frac{x}{x-\delta}k +x < k+1,$$
where the last estimate is satisfied if we take $\delta >0$ small enough.

Comment: Thank you! It should be $p \ge \lceil (k - qn)/(x-\delta) \rceil$, right?

Comment: Also, please explain how you got $\frac{(k-qn)}{x-\delta}x +x+qn < \frac{x}{x-\delta}k +x$

Comment: Here $p=\lceil (k-qn)/(x-\delta)\rceil$ means already taking the minimal natural number $m \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m \geq (k-qn)/(x-\delta)$. That is the usual definition of the ceil-function, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). For the last inequality note that for $\delta =0$ we have $\frac{(k-qn)}{x-\delta}x+x+qn = k+x < k+1$. By continuity we can choose $\delta >0$ small enough such that this inequality is still satisfied. (I have added the $\delta >0$, because otherwise we may have $k=px+qn$. This happens if $(k-qn)/x$ is an integer.)

Comment: Note also that $1< x/(x-\delta)$. Thus, using $qn < \frac{x}{(x-\delta)}qn$ shows $(k-qn)\frac{x}{(x-\delta)}+qn < k \frac{x}{(x-\delta)}$.